# Cosmology without introducing a metric in a manifestly diffeo-invariant way

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, diffeomorphism-invariance

I have a question that bothers me for quite some time:

Can cosmology be done without introducing a metric **explicitly**, and in a **manifestly diffeomorphism-invariant** way? Assuming that we are in the framework of classical general relativity (no modifications/extensions).

Comment: If this were possible, the modern cosmology would not be as wrong as it is.

Comment: But are there any attempts?

Comment: In the Shuttercock model https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Wave-Function-of-the-Universe-Hartle-Hawking/f22a4c2be1a2e434a39752ab29d24527423fcf21?p2df the metric emerges from the wave function of the universe. I talk about this model here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564761/on-the-topic-of-imaginary-time/566286#566286 but not at the depth you are looking for.

Comment: @safesphere thanks for the paper!